# I am getting error while aplying linear regression model

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, timestamp, linear-regression

This is my dataset [image: This is my dataset]

```
x = df.drop(['Order Qty'],axis=1) #training features
y = df['Order Qty']
lm=LinearRegression()
lm.fit(x,y)
```

I am getting error while running this code

TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Timestamp'

Comment: Check all your columns. One of them is a timestamp and cannot be converted to float just like that by the model. Either remove that or convert it to a relevant piece of information for your mode - like a year or quarter or week column.

Answer (score 0):

The linear regression model uses only numeric values, if the input dataframe has a non-numeric column, it tries forcing it to float.
you have a Timestamp type column, which can't be forced to a float.

To solve this, you need to remove that column (or columns if you have several).
Another approach may be to embed the Timestamps into numeric values is some way.